# Windows bat measure execution time

Tags: batch-file

Let's say we got **widnows batch** file named `program.bat` with multiple lines of code. We need to measure execution time of variable blocks of this program.

Is there a simple way of determining time spend using small code chagnes ?

For example by modifying `program.bat` by adding call to function `print_duration`. Each time this function will be called it will print duration since start of the program.

```
call read_some_files
call print_duration
for ...
call process_files
call print_duration
```

with these two lines added to output:

```
Duration: 2 min
Duration: 8 min
```

Comment: I use a hybrid batch file created by Dave Benham called [GetTimeStamp](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4847).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirement. The below demonstrates how to use this. We `call` the start of the timer script before running the code, run the code, then `call` the end of the timer script. so for each command you will call start and end.

```
@echo off
call :start
echo run a command1 here.
call :end
call :start
echo run a command2 here.
call :end
goto :eof

:start
for /f "delims=," %%i in ('powershell -command "(New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-Date "01/01/1970") -End (Get-Date)).TotalSeconds"') do set start=%%i
for /f "delims=," %%i in ('powershell -command "(New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-Date "01/01/1970") -End (Get-Date)).TotalMilliSeconds"') do set mstart=%%i
exit /b
:end
for /f "delims=," %%a in ('powershell -command "(New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-Date "01/01/1970") -End (Get-Date)).TotalSeconds"') do set end=%%a
for /f "delims=," %%a in ('powershell -command "(New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-Date "01/01/1970") -End (Get-Date)).TotalMilliSeconds"') do set mend=%%a
set /a sres=1%end:~-2%-1%start:~-2%
set /a mres=1%mend:~-5%-1%mstart:~-5%%
echo                                                                                        Duration: %sres% sec %mres% ms
set start= | set mstart= | set end= | set mend=
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing. However, this dosn't solve my problem because this launches shell where user types comands and gets results alongside with execution time. I need something that can be applied to existing bat script.